# How to attach footer?

Tags: html, css

I'm going to make "universal" footer to my example of web-site. But I have any problems: 
 1. When page is short - footer doesn't work 
 2. When page is long - footer work

Footer's CSS:

```
.footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-right: -50px;
    width: 110%; 
    height: 70px; 
    background-color: #FF9100;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Footer's HTML:

```
<div class="footer">
        <p>&copy;All rights reserved</p>
</div>
```

Examlpes of images:
[image: Long page]

[image: Short page]

Comment: Why the negative margin-bottom ?

Comment: look at [`position:fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: Also why the width is 110% ?

Comment: @dimshik it's just my decision, negative margine-bottom doesn't make any sense in the problem

Comment: Getting website footers to work, in all possible variations, is a topic that has been discussed to death multiple times over already. Please do some proper research.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.footer {
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed; 
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 70px; 
    background-color: #FF9100;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but I see footer every time. That's problem.

Comment: Can you please share a link to your page ?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `position:fixed` plus a `bottom:0` rules to the `.footer` section, to force it to stay at the bottom of the page.

You can see a very basic code example below

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

main{
  background:url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature');
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  height:100vh;
}

footer{
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1>Example page</h1>
  <footer>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur molestias quos, soluta. Ut dolorum officia illum molestias quia commodi tempora cupiditate, earum deleniti amet sequi deserunt tempore, perferendis harum doloremque.</p>
  </footer>
</main>
```